# oracle procedure cursor query when case statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, case-when, cursors

```
CURSOR BULKUPDATE IS 
    SELECT SUM(B.ACCOUNT_BALANCE) AS ACCOUNT_BALANCE,C.CIF AS CIF_ID FROM _ACCOUNTS_STAGING2 B JOIN  _RELATION_STAGING2 C
    ON B.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER = C.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER AND B.SOURCEID=C.SOURCEID JOIN _CUSTOMER_STAGING2 A ON A.CIF=C.CIF AND A.SOURCEID=C.SOURCEID WHERE  C.ROLE_ON_ACCOUNT IN
    (Select Rollonaccount From _Roleaccount_Master Where Aggregatebalance='Y')
    And upper(B.Scheme_Type) In (Select Scheme_Type From _Schema_Type_Master Where 
    Depository_Account = 'Y') Group By C.Cif;
    Rec_Bulkupdate Bulkupdate%Rowtype;
```

I am using this query to sum account balances based on different cif and source. The question is I want to calculate four different types of sum on the basis of _Schema_Type_Master. For example I want to check now current_account='Y' instead of Depository_Account='Y'

```
_ACCOUNTS_STAGING2 B JOIN  _RELATION_STAGING2 C
    ON B.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER = C.ACCOUNT_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER AND B.SOURCEID=C.SOURCEID JOIN _CUSTOMER_STAGING2 A ON A.CIF=C.CIF AND A.SOURCEID=C.SOURCEID WHERE  C.ROLE_ON_ACCOUNT IN
    (Select Rollonaccount From _Roleaccount_Master Where Aggregatebalance='Y')
    And upper(B.Scheme_Type) In (Select Scheme_Type From _Schema_Type_Master Where 
    current_account='Y') Group By C.Cif;
    Rec_Bulkupdate Bulkupdate%Rowtype;
```

Is there any way or do I need to write four different cursors for that??

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `dipository_account='Y'` and `current_account='Y'` and use case in select as -

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Depository_Account = 'Y' THEN B.ACCOUNT_BALANCE ELSE 0 END) AS DIPOSITORY_ACCOUNT_BALANCE, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN current_account = 'Y' THEN B.ACCOUNT_BALANCE ELSE 0 END) AS CURRENT_ACCOUNT_BALANCE
```

and then rest of your code. You will get two different columns for sum of Depository account and Current account.

And if filter for `dipository_account='Y'` and `current_account='Y'` is required, then use them in where condition with or operator :

```
AND (dipository_account='Y' or current_account='Y')
```